# JRebel compatibility with latest weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic12c, jrebel

In our organization we have been using JRebel 6.3.1. It was working perfectly. Now we have upgraded weblogic to 12.2.1.3. Post this upgrade, the java changes are not being picked up. The JSP changes however are being picked up.
Is there any setting that needs to be done?

Answer (score 3):

WebLogic 12.2.1.3 integration with JRebel has been added in the 7.1.0 version of JRebel.

See changelog: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/changelog/7-x/

Comment: Thank you Tiit. Would that mean I will not be able to use earlier version of Jrebel on latest weblogic?

Comment: @Shashi Technically, you could use an older version of JRebel with WebLogic 12.2.1.3 by disabling JRebel's WebLogic integration but there is no good reason to not update to the latest version. Should there be any additional issues, feel free to contact support at support@zeroturnaround.com